# Unable to populate array of product from database

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jsp, servlets

```
<%@ page language="java" import="controller.*;,java.net.*,java.text.*,java.sql.*, java.util.ArrayList" %>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

<%
// Initialize the array of available products.
    Connection conn=JavaConnect.ConnectDb();
    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM products");
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<model.Item> catalog = new ArrayList();
    while(rs.next()){
       catalog.add (new model.Item(rs.getString(1), rs.getInt(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getInt(5),rs.getInt(6),rs.getInt(7)));
         for (int i=0; i < catalog.size(); i++) {
         model.Item item = catalog.get(i);
                    }


    }


%>

<a href="/shoppingcart/ViewShoppingCart.jsp">View Shopping Cart</a>
<p>
<h1>Available Products</h1>
<table border="1">
<tr><th>EAN</th><th>PIP</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Supplier ID</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
<%

// Get a currency formatter for showing the price.
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    for (int i=0; i < catalog.size(); i++)
    {
        model.Item item = catalog.get(i);

// Create the URL for adding the item to the shopping cart.
        String addItemURL =

            "/shoppingcart/AddToShoppingCartServlet?"+
            "productCode="+URLEncoder.encode(item.getEAN())+
            "&description="+URLEncoder.encode(item.getDescription())+
            "&quantity="+URLEncoder.encode(""+item.getQuantity())+
            "&price="+URLEncoder.encode(""+item.getPrice());
%>
<tr><td><%=item.getDescription()%></td><td><%=item.getQuantity()%>
    </td><td><%=item.getPrice()%></td>
<td><a href="<%=addItemURL%>">Add to Shopping Cart</a></td></tr>
<%
    }
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>






  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

I am getting this new error after using ArrayList. How do I fix this to show my product from database. I have included the new edit to my code and the stacktrace. I dont understand which line 14 it is refereing to.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is happening because there are 2 Item classes which you're importing into your jsp. Either change your imports or put the full class name in the jsp code:

```
controller.Item[] catalog = new controller.Item[100];
```

or

```
 model.Item[] catalog = new model.Item[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully-qualify the class `Item` in use, because there are two classes with the same name in the classpath. What I mean is, instead of

```
new Item(...)
```

Write this:

```
new model.Item(...)
```

To be clear, "fully-qualifying" a class means, writing all the dot-separated packages that lead to the specific class in use.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Item` presented in two packages which you have imported.

```
import="model.*,controller.*
```

So you must specify correct one like

```
 model.Item[] catalog=new model.Item[100]; //or
 controller.Item[] catalog=new controller.Item[100];
```

Also instead of using Array you can use collection

```
 ArrayList<model.Item> itemList = new ArrayList();
```

then add for each row

```
itemlist.add (new model.Item(rs.getString(1), 
         rs.getInt(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getInt(5),
         rs.getInt(6),rs.getInt(7));
```

use ArrayList

```
 for (int i=0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    model.Item item = itemList.get(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. avoid duplicate import
2. give fully qualified class name along with instance variables if you want to access.
3. you can even use static import if your class and methods are static.